# Is it possible to extract precise decision boundaries from a random forest for a multiclass classification?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-trees, ensemble-learning

I have a random forest (argmax post-processor) with 3 trees and 10 input features. The final outcome of the random forest is either true or false depending on the combination of the feature values. Is there a way to extract the precise decision boundaries for each class (True/False)?

What I'm looking for:

Class: True

Tree 1: feature 1 < 5.6 and feature 4 > 2.3

Tree 2: feature 3 > 3.1 and feature 7 > 8.9

Tree 3: feature 2 > 0.9 and feature 8 < 1.2

Comment: Answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224526/how-to-extract-the-decision-rules-from-scikit-learn-decision-tree

Comment: Yes, but that is for a decision tree. I’m asking how to do it for a Random Forest with an argmax post processing function.

Comment: Random Forest do not have such feature, as the decision is made upon individual trees, and then the probabilities are averaged, not the boundaries, as you can see here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L890 .

Comment: Is it then possible to have a joint contour plot of all the regions (of each tree) for a particular class? with the darker colors representing a higher probability?